# Folding over a Rose Tree : Tree a -> [a]

Tags: haskell

I posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26922761/folding-over-rose-tree) on StackOverflow.

Given this algebraic data type:

```
data Tree a = Node {
    rootLabel :: a,
    subForest :: [Tree a]
}  deriving (Show)
```

and function:

```
treeFold :: (a -> [b] -> b) -> Tree a -> b
treeFold f (Node x ts) = f x (map (treeFold' f) ts)
```

Write a function (using `treeFold`) with the signature: `Tree a -> [a]`.

Given this example:

```
ghci> stringTree
Node {rootLabel = "foo", 
      subForest = [Node {rootLabel = "bar",   subForest = []},
                   Node {rootLabel = "bippy", subForest = []},
                   Node {rootLabel = "baz", subForest = []} ]}
```

I came up with:

```
ghci> treeFold' (\x y -> x : (join y) ) stringTree
["foo","bar","bippy","baz"]
```

Please review this implementation.

I'm not sure if introducing `join` here (from `Control.Monad`) is overkill. Note that I don't have a good sense as to whether it's OK to casually use Monads - mainly using the right abstraction - not going overboard.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that using monads here itself is overkill,
but I would suggest using `concat` instead of `join`.

There are no different Monads that could be an argument 
to `join` here. Using `concat` is more apropriate (imo).